# Script works in IE, not working in FF?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, internet-explorer-8

```
function AddRow(){
var rowCount = $("td.RowClass").length;
var currentIndex = 0;
if (rowCount > 0)
{
    currentIndex = rowCount--;
}

var markup = '<tr>';
markup += '<td class="RowClass" style="width:250px"><input type="text" id="TomId' + currentIndex + '" maxlength="78" size="70" /></td>';
markup += '<td><input style="width:245px" type="text" id="SerialNumber' + currentIndex + '" maxlength="30" size="25" />&nbsp&nbsp';

if (currentIndex >= 1) 
{
    markup += '<a id="removeTom' + currentIndex + '" href="#" onclick="RemoveTomControls(' + currentIndex + ')">Remove</a>';
}

markup += '</td></tr>';
$('#dataTable > tbody').append(markup);
}
```

here's the the html I'm appending to:

```
<div style="height:340px; overflow:auto;">
            <table id="dataTable" style="margin:0px 1px 10px 5px; margin: width:800px;"> 
            </table>
       </div>
```

Comment: Any error messages? Does it do anything in FF?  What's it supposed to do?

Comment: "Script works in IE, not working in FF?" Lol mate. All the time, all the time...

Comment: I would supply the HTML if I were you.  The problem is most likely in the selector for the append at the bottom.

Comment: Just as a heads up, you can replace `var rowCount = 0; $("td.RowClass").each(function() { rowCount++; });` with `var rowCount = $("td.RowClass").length;`

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but you can count up your rows more efficiently with this:  `rowCount = $("td.RowClass").length;`  Damnit Nick  :)

Comment: Incidentally, you can get the row count easier than that: `var rowCount = $('td.RowClass').size();`.  Also you are decrementing `rowCount` in order to create `currentIndex`, OK, you are not using `rowCount` again, but you probably did not intend that.

Comment: I love these questions that assume Firefox is to blame.  Question should be "Why does this broken JavaScript work in IE?"

Comment: @Stehpen, if it's broken javascript, what's wrong with it? That's what I'm asking...not assuming FF is at fault..

Comment: @Nick Surreal Orbling, thanks, I figured there was a more effcient way to do that :)

Comment: @Surreal, no error messages. No, it doesnt do anything in FF. The script appends a row to a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox, unlike IE, won't infer a tbody element unless there is at least one tr in your table.

So `$('#dataTable > tbody')` matches nothing and your append has no effect.